# Shelves algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

SHELVES Problem:
Input: The ﬁrst line of the input contains the number N  1000 of test cases. Then N lines
follow. Each line is a test-case and contains 3 strictly positive integers l, m and n. The number
l< 2^31
31 denotes the length of the wall, while m and n denote the length of the two shelf types,
m <=n < 2^31

Output: For each test case you should output the optimal number of shelves of length m and n
such that the sum of their lengths is at most `and as close to` as possible. If there are multiple
solutions you should prefer the one which uses the largest amount of shelves of length n.
For each test case output one line containing 3 integers separated by a single space. The ﬁrst two
integers are the number of shelves of length m and n, the third is the amount of wall that remains
uncovered in an optimal solution.
Sample input
3
24 3 5
29 3 9
42 4 5
Sample output
3 3 0
0 3 2
3 6 0

This is my program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int G=1;

void foo(int l,int m,int n,int part1)
{
    int part2;
    if(m==0)
        part2=0;
    else
        part2=(l-part1*n)/m;
    if(part1*n+part2*m==l)
    {
        cout<<part2<<" "<<part1<<" 0"<<endl;
        G=0;
    }
    else
        if(part1>0)
        {
            foo(l,m,n,part1-1);

        }
}




int main()
{
    int l,nn=0,m,n=0,part1,part2,rem;
    cin>>nn;
    while(nn!=0)
    {
        G=1;
        cin>>l>>m>>n;
        part1=l/n;
        foo(l,m,n,part1);
        if(G==1)
        {
            part1=l/n;
            part2=(l-part1*n)/m;
            rem=l-(part1*n+part2*m);
            cout<<part2<<" "<<part1<<" "<<rem<<endl;
        }
        nn--;
    }


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This program is evalurate dby an online judge.He says my sample data is evaluated right,but large data and some more are not.So i dont know why my program take sa long time.

Thanks

Comment: What data doesn't evaluate right? Is it perhaps because of an integer overflow?

Comment: I am not sure.its an online judge in our college website.It evaluates how fast,is the prog exeeds 1 min and all..Name Result Points CPU Time
1 samle wrong-answer 0 0s
2 large wrong-answer 0 0.003s
3 howaboutthis wrong-answer 0 0s

Comment: all my inputs work fine tough.and the judge is not wrong.i dunno where im wrong

Comment: You might try using 'long int' instead of 'int' to see if that fixes the incorrect value. Also, there is nothing in this code that should take a long time to process. I do wonder if that last getch() is causing the program to hang and appear as though it's taking a long time though. If it's an automated process, it may just be fooled by that, so you might try removing that before your next submission.

Comment: I did.It doesnt accept a getch() at all.It is very strange.I am not able to process it....